# Passing XML data as query string in the URL

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a XML file inside the project folder and need to pass XML data as a query parameter in order to open a new page.

I have successfully read the XML file from the folder but could not able to send the data as a query parameter. I tried in the following way but getting like,

`http://localhost:8080/newpage?param=[object%20XMLDocument]`

```
function readXML() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'xml/sample.xml', true);

        xhr.onload = function () {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
        var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/newpage?param="+ xmlDoc;
      };
     xhr.send(null);
 }
```

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeuri

Comment: xmlDoc is an object and is not being serilalised, perhaps you meant `var xmlDoc = xhr.responseText`